# iOS: holding down a button and gesture recognizing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

In my application i would like two modes of gesture recognition, which are identified according to a button. When the button is held down, the gestures should be handled differently than when the button is up.

The problem is that the finger holding the button is recognized as part of the gesture, so instead of getting single-finger-pan notification i get pinch or rotation notification.

Is it possible to prevent the finger holding the button to be part of the gesture?

Comment: Are you just implementing this using only gesture recognizers? Can we see some code?

Comment: What are your UIGestureRecognizers right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

what i had to do is to ignore any touches not on my view. I achieved it using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return (touch.view == self.view);
}
```